# Sending notification to mobile app with FCM and AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, aws-lambda, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I am currently implement a project using Firebase Cloud Messagin (FCM) to send notification to mobile apps, the scenario is when "something happends", the hardware device can send the notification to all the mobile devices that belongs to it. (Hardware to mobile device is One to Many)

Simply, I implemented two APIs. The first one is for the app to store the devices' device tokens which are given by FCM to my server. The other one is for the hardware device to call and push notification to all the mobile devices that belong to it.

```
App -> FCM -> (register device and receive device token) -> save to my server
Hardware -> my server -> (retrieve all the mobile devices' token from DB) -> (call FCM send API) -> (push notification to app)
```

The framework described above works fine now. However, as the number of hardware devices increase, it may cause quite high load to my server. I am considering to use the AWS Simple Notification Service (SNS) in this case, but seems that AWS SNS can deal with the part of calling FCM API, my server still need to store the EndPoint ARN for AWS SNS to map to the devices.
Any advice on implementing AWS SNS in this case?